# rsync from Mac ext hd to VPS works but not VPS to Mac

Tags: osx, rsync

There are no errors with either

`rsync -a /Volumes/hd/dir_foo  foo@foo.com:~/`

or

`rsync -a foo@foo.com:~/dir_foo /Volumes/hd/dir_foo`

in the first instance the synced folder on remote system CentOs successfully transfers.

However, going the opposite way terminal just lists the contents but on Mac ext HD there is no folder or contents moved there.

Practising rsync before attempting to save VPS to my local ext drive.

This Is what it prints in terminal

```
   MyName-iMac:VPSbackups myname$ rsync -a root@mysite.net:~/testingrsync/test2.flv
   root@mysite.net's password: 
   -rw-r--r--   661072538 2014/04/04 14:09:50 test2.flv
```

Is it because I have to declare the path of local folder not simply reside in it at command?

Comment: Please show the *real* command you are attempting to run. My first thought is that `nullglob` is set, and you're using something that is being interpreted as a glob.

Comment: That is the real command just replacing my names with foo.

Comment: I named testing directory testingrsync but other than that the names are mine and server name

Comment: @ChrisDown I wouldn't be at all surprised if something interprets me as a glob haha

Comment: You're missing where to copy to in that example you posted...

Comment: Yes because I was sitting in the folder I want copied to - but now the flv file is taking a hundred years to dload so cannot even imagine what an entire system would take.

Comment: I am using --verbose to see what is going on- i cannot imagine it just very slow .

Comment: That's not how it works. If you're in the same directory, you still need to specify it (with `.`, or another reference). This is the reason why it does not work.

Comment: Ok but then why is one file taking more than 10 minutes to dload - that couldn't be right?

Comment: Anyway I think I worked that out for myself but thanks :) Now if it is this slow I cannot be bothered- I must find another way.

Comment: That is an entirely different issue, which with no knowledge of your situation, I have absolutely no way to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real world example shows that you are missing the destination. If you want to copy to the current directory, use `.`:

```
rsync -a root@mysite.net:~/testingrsync/test2.flv .
```